# $mg\cos\theta=N$ or $N\cos\theta=mg$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

I was reading up of centripetal motion when I saw the relation that $mg=N\cos\theta$, as can be seen from http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Mechanics/carbank.html, in the case of a frictionless plane.

This contradicted with what I was taught before.  A block sliding down a ramp has a normal force perpendicular to the surface, which is equal to $mg\cos\theta$.  This video here  https://youtu.be/0GnqKxtnXoo says the same thing.

I am stumped by this contradiction!  Which one is correct?

Comment: It's just not that simple, it's different in different situations.

Comment: Think back to algebra. They have you solve for $x$, but one day $x = 2$ and the next day $x = 5$! Which one is correct? Depends on the problem.

Comment: Are you implying that N is different in the two cases?

Comment: Well, yes. They're totally different setups. There's no reason to expect they would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the gravitational force $mg$ is directed ONLY in vertical direction; Independent of the Problem you have. Normal Forces depend on the incline of the plane.

In cases where you have seen the equation $mg \cos \theta = N$ you have the correct expression to compute the component of the force directing towards the normal. The force that Acts parallel to the plane (what lets the block slide downwards) is then $F_d = mg \sin \theta$.

On the Website, where it was proposed $mg = N \cos \theta$ the angle $\theta$ was defined as the angle between vertical axis (where the gravitational force acts) and the normal direction of the plane. There was defined a completely different trigonometry. The force $N \cos \theta$ is the vertical component of the force. But, when you compute the Expression $N \sin \theta$ you get only the force in the x-direction (according to the website), which is NOT the plane-downward directed force (x-direction is not the direction parallel to the plane)!

So, $N=mg \cos \theta$ is correct for the normal force if the block slides down a plane with angle $\theta$.

Comment: The website says that theta is also the angle of slope.  It is defined in the same way.  It’s just by angle chasing the angle formed between N and the vertical is the same